# Route resource not defined laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to insert data in laravel 5.3, I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to use the resource routing system. When I load my page I get -

```
InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314:
Route [/admin/register-account.store] not defined.
```

**Routes**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
   //Applicaion home
   Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

   //Admin routes
   Route::get('/admin/home', 'AdminController@index');

   //Register Account Routes
   Route::resource('/admin/register-account', 'RegAccController');

});
```

**Form**

```
<form action="{{ route('/admin/register-account.store') }}" type="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Account name" name="acc_name" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Account location" name="acc_location" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Account website" name="acc_website" />

        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
        <button type="submit" class="primary-btn">Register Account</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
     'acc_name' => 'required',
     'acc_location' => 'required',
     'acc_website' => 'required',
  ]);

  $regAcc = new Account;
  $regAcc->name = $request->name;
  $regAcc->website = $request->acc_location;
  $regAcc->location = $request->acc_website;
  $regAcc->save();

  return view('admin.reg-acc');
}
```

I believe my issue is where I define the form action name however I've tried a number of combinations and I can't seem to get another error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're using [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route) helper, you should use [name of the resource route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers), not path.

> The `route()` function generates a URL for the given **named route**

For example:

```
{{ route('register-account.store') }}
```

You can see actual routes names with executing this command (see `Name` column):

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: Aha - excellent! The page now loads and once the form is submitted it reloads as expected however data isn't stored in the db. I have a test record in their which is output on another page successfully. 

I'll look at that route list command seems very helpful!